# Store MSAL logged-in users and precheck them before doing a request on node.js web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-ad-msal

In my node project I have the following basic code to connect to Azure via a token. The login/logout works great together with our Azure:

```
const express = require("express");
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');
const SERVER_PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "XXX",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
        clientSecret: "XXX"
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
                console.log(message);
            },
            piiLoggingEnabled: false,
            logLevel: msal.LogLevel.Verbose,
        }
    }
};
const pca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config);
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("<a href=\"login\">Login</a> <a href=\"logout\">Logout</a>");
});
app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
    // check here for valid token...
});
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    const authCodeUrlParameters = {
        scopes: ["user.read"],
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/redirect",
    };
    pca.getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParameters).then((response) => {
        res.redirect(response);
    }).catch((error) => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
});
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/');
});
app.get('/redirect', (req, res) => {
    const tokenRequest = {
        code: req.query.code,
        scopes: ["user.read"],
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/redirect",
    };
    pca.acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest).then((response) => {
        console.log("\nResponse: \n:", response);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }); 
});
app.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => console.log(`Msal Node Auth Code Sample app listening on port ${SERVER_PORT}!`))
```

But how to properly check after that logging in if the token is still valid?

So the question is, how can I be save that the user on /dashboard has still a valid token or is logged in?

```
app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
    // check here for valid token...
});
```

At the end I need a node.js application that:

- is safe (token-based)
- has user auth (msal)
- can give granular permissions on routes

Can I do all that in node.js or better doing that in client-side? But am I then reducing the security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the **silent-flow** was a good idea. It works great on my example.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-node-samples/standalone-samples/silent-flow

This works with the `PublicClientApplication` and `acquireTokenSilent` works also as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get your authentication result the first time, this should have received tokens if authentication was successful. You should be able to parse the Id token to get information about the user. You can then use that information to create a session via the web framework that you are using. The session can be used thorough out the web app to give you information like if the user is authenticated or not, how long they are authenticated for, and what they have permission to access. Usually web frameworks will create a cookie with a session id so that requests coming in will be able to have session information, and the user won't have to authenticate every time.

If the session expires, you can try acquiring a token silently (without prompting the user) by using the token cache that is part of MSAL. When you call acquire token silent, MSAL will automatically check if the access token is valid, if not it will try to refresh the access token via the refresh token. If neither are valid, they will return an error. At this point you can fall back to prompting the user again to authenticate (via the code that you have already shared).

Comment: Very good answer for the moment, but I cannot see how to achieve my task in detail. So as I understand you say that I did it correct via '/redirect' but on the callback I need to  set the cookie token on client-side. But what is that token? Is it the GET parameter in the URL or something different? And can you maybe give some code to check that token against AD? But what happens in the case the user logs out, then simply delete the cookie? And is it good for the security that the user is able to fake the token? I know that usual websites also doing it in this way. But is that best practice?

Comment: The token is the value returned form the `acquireToken` call. It is a JWT. In the case when the user logs out, next time he accesses your app again you'll redirect him to AAD again where he will put his credentials. I don't understand your question "And is it good for the security that the user is able to fake the token". The JWTs returned by AzureAD are signed, so the user (or anyone else) can't fake them. You can always validate the token by validating the signature on the JWT.

Comment: Maybe I still got you wrong. So for the question of security have a look on my client-side solution. This is kind of what you described I think. Saving token and on each request check that token. But as happening on client-side its not safe. Maybe you could show me how to check that token on server-side? Because I was not able to find that from the MSAL documentation. That server-side `aquireToken` would be my solution.

Comment: MSAL is only used for acquiring tokens, and does not support token validation. For token validation server-side, you can use a library such as https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken. They should have documentation and samples showing how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a kind of dirty way to solve my issue. Could you maybe tell me if that is a proper way? Also my solution is not safe as the user could change the client-side JS code and ignore the user auth.

Create HTML file for `/dashboard`:

```
app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "index.html");
});
```

and here using this JS code:

```
var headers = new Headers();
var bearer = "Bearer " + "ey...........Ac"; // <---- accessToken
headers.append("Authorization", bearer);
var options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
};
var graphEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me";

fetch(graphEndpoint, options)
    .then(resp => {
         // when error redirect to ... otherwise do log:
         console.log(123);
    });
```

on the `<---- accessToken` putting a valid token and it works. Only when token is valid the console.log is done.

So this works, but as I said, if the user is manipulating the code he can still see the page. Also the page is loading until the script is fired. So I cannot see a real value on this. This should happen on server-side somehow. Any idea?

Comment: Instead of executing this JS code on the client, why can't you execute it on the server (as part of the `app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res)` call)?  Instead of returning JS code to the client to then be executed, you instead return the result of the call to the graphEndpoint.